# Software to monitor hard disk recent changes

Tags: windows-7, file-management, monitoring, disk-analysis

I want a software to show recent changes to the hard disk(any type external or internal). which file recently has been copied to the hard and which has been deleted,renamed,etc.

the software can log information about files in a file or any other ways, but it must show me the changes to the hard disk.

Is there any software to has the abilities (or some of them) mentioned above?

my operating system is windows 7.

tnx in advance.

Comment: Thanks, Abdolah! Much clearer now. But still one thing missing: "must show me the changes" is to be understood as "when I check the logs/GUI/whatever, it must list all changes (including what details?)" – or "whenever there were changes, it must notify me (by which means: mail? what interval?) with a list of changes (what details?)"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are running Windows 7 you already have the monitoring software installed on your system since NTFS is a journalling file system - provided journalling has been enabled, (if not you can use a command like: `fsutil usn createjournal m=1000 a=100 c:` to enable it for C:), on the specified disk/volume you can use a journal analyser such as [this one](https://tzworks.net/prototype_page.php?proto_id=5) from TZWorks to display and/or dump the information.

[image]

Comment: Good point, Steve! How long are entries kept in that? I doubt it stores them "eternally". Is there a limit by time or by entries? Can it be adjusted (increased usually)?

Comment: Oldest entries are deleted - how much there is is controlled by m=<MaxSize> - Specifies the maximum size, in bytes, that NTFS allocates for the change journal.
a=<AllocationDelta> Specifies the size, in bytes, of memory allocation that is added to the end and removed from the beginning of the change journal.